# Unable to bind a URL property to html page using ngx-sharebuttons

Tags: angular, firebase-dynamic-links, socialshare

I am receiving a dynamic link from firebase's rest apis.

**social.ts**

```
this.shareUrl = res.shortLink; //dynamic link is stored in this  variable from the response.
```

Now I am trying to provide this.shareUrl(short link) on a social share button used from ngx-sharebuttons.

**social.html**

```
<share-buttons class="mb-2 mt-2" [theme]="'circles-dark'" 
[include]="'facebook','twitter','whatsapp']" [show]="9" [url]="'this.shareUrl'">
</share-buttons>
```

I also tried `[url]  = "{{this.shareUrl}}"`

I want to share this dynamic link across whatsapp, FB ad twitter. I'd appreciate if someone could help me fix this or share an alternative to social share this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes or you will be binding a literal string:

```
[url]="this.shareUrl"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but that doesn't work. It still shares the current page I am in http://localhost:4200/mypage on whatapp.

Comment: @amusicalwish That's unrelated to this question. So I suggest you open another question with that problem.

Comment: Yeh you were correct, thanks for the quick help.